# discord.py command if no @member given

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to make it so if I type just `?lol` it prints `'987654321'`, but if I type `?lol @member` and mention someone it prints `'123456789'`

```
@commands.command()
async def lol(self, ctx, *, member: discord.Member):
    if member:
        print('123456789')
    else:
        print('987654321')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did almost everything right. However, you need to set `discord.Member` to `None` in your command.

Only then the bot will not see `member` as needed and will automatically output the value for `None`. If you then mention a member, your defined number will be displayed.

```py
@commands.command()
async def lol(self, ctx, *, member: discord.Member = None):
    if member:
        print('123456789')
        #await ctx.send("Member mentioned") # As you passed in ctx
    else:
        print('987654321')
        #await ctx.send("No member mentioned.")
```